# Problema rutas php - PATH

Tags: php, mvc

Buenas tardes a tod@s!

Os cuento mi problema: Tengo una archivo en el que puedo publicar un anuncio, pero antes debo de hacer un include al archivo de configuracion, donde se encuentran las variables de conexion y demás. El caso es que probando y probando no soy capaz de hacer el include. Los archivos estan subidos en un servidor del colegio, a continuacion os dejare la estructura de archivos y a ver como puedo conseguir hacer el include. Muchas gracias de antemano!

```
   //comprobamos si la extension actual es una de las disponibles en el array $allowed
if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
    //comprobamos que no hay ningun error
    if ($fileError === 0) {
        //comprobamos el tamaño del archivo (kb)
        if ($fileSize < 10000000) {
            /*$rootPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            echo "esta es la ruta " . $rootPath;
            echo $rootPath . '/config/dbh.inc.php';
            include_once($rootPath . '/config/dbh.inc.php');*/
            include_once('../config/dbh.inc.php');

            //nuevo nombre aleatorio para que nunca se repitan
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = $rootPath . 'uploads/'. $fileNameNew;
```

Como veis, el problema viene en el `include_once('../config/dbh.inc.php);` que se encuentra en el archivo `componentes/uploadAd/model.php`

Y aqui la estructura del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intenta haciendo `if(!is_readable('include.php')){ die("el archivo no se puede leer"); }` para validar que exista y sea legible!

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez esto debería ser un comentario, pero no tengo suficiente reputación, me parece que tienes que subir un nivel mas en la ruta del archivo, Si tu archivo esta en `/www/componentes/uploadAd/` y subes solo un nivel, estarás buscando una carpeta `/www/componentes/config/` que según las imágenes no existe, si subes 2 niveles si encontraras `/www/config`

`include_once('../../config/dbh.inc.php');`

Comment: y como seria? ././config/dbh.inc.php??

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta con la linea apropiada

Comment: funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias!